# Pass stream data from multiprocess to asyncio

Tags: python, macos, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, cryptofeed

I am trying to use the cryptofeed module to receive API OHLC data, store the data in a global variable by placing the cryptofeed stream in a separate multiprocessing thread, then accessing the global variable from a separate asyncio instance.

I am having trouble storing the global data using the multiprocess, the async function of close(), returns an empty pandas dataframe. I would like a suggestion on how to approach this problem.

```
from cryptofeed import FeedHandler
from cryptofeed.backends.aggregate import OHLCV
from cryptofeed.defines import TRADES
from cryptofeed.exchanges import BinanceFutures 
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Process
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import asyncio

data1 = pd.DataFrame()  # Create an empty DataFrame
queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

async def ohlcv(data):
    global data1
    # Convert data to a Pandas DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
    # Reset the index
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df.index = [pd.Timestamp.now()]
    data1 = data1.append(df)
    queue.put('nd')
    # Append the rows of df to data

async def close(data):
    while True:
        print(data)
        await asyncio.sleep(15)

def main1():
    f = FeedHandler()
    f.add_feed(BinanceFutures(symbols=['BTC-USDT-PERP'], channels=[TRADES], callbacks={TRADES: OHLCV(ohlcv, window=10)}))
    f.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=main1)
    p.start()
    asyncio.run(close(data1))
```

Comment: `close` doesn't return anything contrary to what you say. And if `data1` is modified in some process other than the main process, which appears to be the case, then there is no way that `data` could be anything other than an empty `dataframe` in the main process. Where does `queue` enter into this? You are just putting an element on the queue that nobody seems to be reading.  See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And tag your question with the OS you are running under (Windows? Linux?).

Comment: @Booboo Thanks for your input. main1 returns values via callback function to ohlcv(), which it converts to pandas dataframe and stores it in the global variable data1, which was declared outside of the ohlcv function. When doing print(data1) in the ohlcv function it prints its values. When printing outside of ohlcv and outside of the multiprocessing thread (in close() asyncio function), it outputs a empty dataframe. Assumingly multiprocessing and asyncio does not share memory

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to combine asyncio with multiprocessing in some fashion. I don't have access to your `FeedHandler` and `BinanceFutures` classes, so I will just have `main1` directly call `ohlcv` and since it is running in a separate process from the main process, which is using `asyncio`, I can't see any reason with the code you posted why `oh1cv` would need to be a coroutine (`asyncio` function).

`asyncio` has a provision for running multiprocessing tasks and that is the way to proceed. So we run `close` as a coroutine and it runs `main1` in a child process (a multiprocessing pool process, actually) returning back the result that was returned from `main1`. There is no need for explicit queue operations to return any result:

```py
import asyncio
import pandas as pd
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def ohlcv(data):
    # Convert data to a Pandas DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
    # Reset the index
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df.index = [pd.Timestamp.now()]
    return df

def main1():
    """
    f = FeedHandler()
    f.add_feed(BinanceFutures(symbols=['BTC-USDT-PERP'], channels=[TRADES], callbacks={TRADES: OHLCV(ohlcv, window=10)}))
    f.run()
    """

    return ohlcv({'a': 1})

async def close():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(1) as executor:
        return await loop.run_in_executor(executor, main1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = asyncio.run(close())
    print(df)
```

Prints:

```None
                           index  0
2023-01-08 15:59:44.939261     a  1
```

Comment: Tried this implementation, the print(df) function does not get triggered. I tried putting a print(df) function at the ohlcv() function, it printed the correct output. @Booboo

Comment: Note: f.run module uses asyncio uvloops

Comment: Well, see my original comment about posting a minimal, reproducible example, which helps us to help you. So `f.run` uses `asyncio`. You should be able to make the necessary changes then from what I posted. The main point was how to have a coroutine (`close` in this case) do processing in a child process, which hopefully I have demonstrated.

Comment: Sorry for being difficult. I am trying to implement this however it seems like the entire process is stuck on the feedhandler and is not running things concurrently, i.e, the print(df) is not being executed. i will try other implementations such as running multiple processes with shared memory.

Comment: Why not try to post code that abstracts whatever the difficulty you are encountering is? That is, try to duplicate the problem with *simpler* code that I can run and perhaps correct. If we can figure out what's wrong with that simpler code that demonstrates the same problem, then you will be able to apply the solution to your actual code, perhaps.

Comment: Sorry just not sure how to reproduce this. It seems that feedhandler in main1, does not have a return or await, and is blocking other processes. this is assumption from what i gathered.